# Reusable React-Query API call

Tags: reactjs, react-query

i have a page which onload, will make 3 API calls. If a user clicks on a Card, a modal opens and makes another API call to populate the Modal.

I've tried to create a reusable hook to wrap useQuery but I was not able to use it when a user clicks on the modal as I can't use a hook within a function.

Is there another strategy to create a reusable function around useQuery?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useMemo} from "react"
import Card from "../Common/Card"
import {useSelector} from "react-redux"
import Overlay from "../Common/Overlay"
import axios from "axios"
import {apiSubDirectory} from "../../Constants"
import {useQueryClient, useQuery} from "react-query"

export default function OverallOrderCommunicationServiceStatus() {

    const onSuccess = (data) => {
        console.log("Perform side effect after success", data.data)
    }

    const onSuccessResults = (data) => {
        console.log("Perform side effect after onSuccessResults", data.data)
        setApiData(data.data)
    }
    const onError = (error) => {
        console.log('Perform side effect after error', error)
    }

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [dataToFetch, setDataToFetch] = useState("");
    const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

    const environmentMapping = useSelector(
        (state) => state.env.environmentMapping
    );

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const urlOverallPreviousStatus = `${apiSubDirectory}getLatestTestStatus/?testSuiteName=EMAILS&environment=${environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}&status=complete&triggerSource=SCHEDULED`
    const urlOverallCurrentStatus = `${apiSubDirectory}getLatestTestStatus/?testSuiteName=EMAILS&environment=${environmentMapping[1].current.environment}&status=complete&triggerSource=SCHEDULED`
    const urlOverallNextStatus = `${apiSubDirectory}getLatestTestStatus/?testSuiteName=EMAILS&environment=${environmentMapping[2].next.environment}&status=complete&triggerSource=SCHEDULED`

    const fetchPreviousOverallStatus = () => { return axios.get(urlOverallPreviousStatus) }
    const fetchCurrentOverallStatus = () => { return axios.get(urlOverallCurrentStatus) }
    const fetchNextOverallStatus = () => { return axios.get(urlOverallNextStatus) }

    const { isLoading:isLoading1, data:data1, isError:isError1, error:error1, isFetching:isFetching1, refetch:refetch1 } = useQuery('overallPreviousStatus', fetchPreviousOverallStatus, {
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        enabled: true
    })
    const { isLoading:isLoading2, data:data2, isError:isError2, error:error2, isFetching:isFetching2, refetch:refetch2 } = useQuery('overallCurrentStatus', fetchCurrentOverallStatus, {
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        enabled: true
    })
    const { isLoading:isLoading3, data:data3, isError:isError3, error:error3, isFetching:isFetching3, refetch:refetch3 } = useQuery('overallNextStatus', fetchNextOverallStatus, {
        onSuccess,
        onError,
        enabled: true
    })

    const fetchPreviousOcsTestResults = () => {
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?a=${environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}`)
    }

    const fetchCurrentOcsTestResults = () => {
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?a=${environmentMapping[1].current.environment}`)
    }

    const fetchNextOcsTestResults = () => {
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?a=${environmentMapping[2].next.environment}`)
    }

    const { isLoading:isLoading4, data:data4, isError:isError4, error:error4, isFetching:isFetching4 } = useQuery('previousOcsTestResults', fetchPreviousOcsTestResults, {
        onSuccess:onSuccessResults,
        onError,
        enabled: false
    })

    const { isLoading:isLoading5, data:data5, isError:isError5, error:error5, isFetching:isFetching5 } = useQuery('currentOcsTestResults', fetchCurrentOcsTestResults, {
        onSuccess:onSuccessResults,
        onError,
        enabled: false
    })

    const { isLoading:isLoading6, data:data6, isError:isError6, error:error6, isFetching:isFetching6 } = useQuery('nextOcsTestResults', fetchNextOcsTestResults, {
        onSuccess:onSuccessResults,
        onError,
        enabled: false
    })

    const fetchPreviousData = async () => {
        await queryClient.refetchQueries('previousOcsTestResults');
    };

    const fetchCurrentData = async () => {
        await queryClient.refetchQueries('currentOcsTestResults');
    };

    const fetchNextData = async () => {
        await queryClient.refetchQueries('nextOcsTestResults');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOpen) {
            if (dataToFetch === "previous") {
                fetchPreviousData()
            } else if (dataToFetch === "current") {
                fetchCurrentData()
            } else if (dataToFetch === "next") {
                fetchNextData()
            }
        }
    }, [isOpen]);


    const columns = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "title",
        },
    ], [])

    const handlePopupOpen = (dataToFetch) => {
        setIsOpen(true);
        setDataToFetch(dataToFetch);
    };

    const handlePopupClose = () => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 ml-sm-auto col-lg-12 mt-5">
                    <div className="row mt-5">
                        <div className="card-group">
                            <Card
                                environmentName={environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}
                                releaseno="CCB Environment"
                                onClick={() => handlePopupOpen("previous")}
                            />

                            {environmentMapping[0].previous.isEnvironmentReady ? (

                                isOpen && (
                                    <Overlay
                                        environment={environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}
                                        onClose={handlePopupClose}
                                        show={isOpen}
                                        columns={columns}
                                        apiData={apiData}
                                    />
                                )
                            ) : (
                                <React.Fragment />
                            )}

                            <Card
                                environmentName={environmentMapping[0].previous.environment}
                                releaseno="CCB Environment"
                                onClick={() => handlePopupOpen("previous")}
                            />

                            {environmentMapping[1].current.isEnvironmentReady ? (

                                isOpen && (
                                    <Overlay
                                        environment={environmentMapping[1].current.environment}
                                        onClose={handlePopupClose}
                                        show={isOpen}
                                        columns={columns}
                                        apiData={apiData}
                                    />
                                )
                            ) : (
                                <React.Fragment />
                            )}

                            <Card
                                environmentName={environmentMapping[2].next.environment}
                                releaseno="CCB Environment"
                                onClick={() => handlePopupOpen("previous")}
                            />

                            {environmentMapping[2].next.isEnvironmentReady ? (

                                isOpen && (
                                    <Overlay
                                        environment={environmentMapping[2].next.environment}
                                        onClose={handlePopupClose}
                                        show={isOpen}
                                        columns={columns}
                                        apiData={apiData}
                                    />
                                )
                            ) : (
                                <React.Fragment />
                            )}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

What I have tried in a new JS file:

```
import { useQuery as useBaseQuery } from 'react-query';

const defaultOptions = { method: 'GET' };
async function fetcher(url, options = defaultOptions) {
    const resp = await fetch(url, options);
    return await resp.json();
}

export function useQuery(queryKey, query) {
    return useBaseQuery(queryKey, async () => {
        return await fetcher(query);
    });
}
```